# Keeping record of the previously selected tab

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

Imagine you have a `TabControl` in which you can close the `TabPage` and reorder them as wanted. You wish to reassign the previously selected page after closing one, so you need to keep record of the previous index. You finally ask yourself: Is it possible to have an event that triggers before the `SelectedIndex` of a `TabControl` changes?

Then you search all the events proposed by the `TabControl` and the closest one you find is the `SelectedIndexChanged` which takes an `EventArgs` parameter that contains no information on the previous index.

You also tried to keep record of the previous index with an `OnClick` event but failed as the closing capability of the control makes this approach impossible.

Why is this approach impossible? Because when you close a tab, you select it as well, so you end up having `SelectedIndex == PreviouIndex`, `Dispose()` this page and having no tab selected at all.

So you finally decide to come here and ask the same question: Is it possible to have an event that triggers **before** the `SelectedIndex` of a `TabControl` changes? **If not**, what would be the best way to keep the previously selected index ?

Comment: I imagine the `Selecting` and `Deselecting` events are probably what you want to use.  They pass the `TabControlCancelEventArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like LarsTech suggested, I used Deselecting and proceeded as follow:

```
// Class definition ...
public TabPage PreviousTab { get; private set;}   
private void Deselecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
if (e.TabPage != null)
PreviousTab = e.TabPage;
}
```